# Splitting a 3D mesh based on sharpness

Tags: mesh, vtk

I am trying to automate the detection of (more or less) circular cross sections from an input stl mesh of parts of the vascular system. To do this I am using the vtk library in Python to split my mesh based on the angle between neighboring normals. It seems to be working correctly but I cannot save the different parts of my mesh in different files.

Here is the code I am using :

```
import vtk

# Load input mesh
reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
reader.SetFileName("mesh.stl")
reader.Update()

# Compute sharpness
mesh = reader.GetOutput()
normals = vtk.vtkPolyDataNormals()
normals.SetInputData(mesh)
normals.ComputePointNormalsOff()
normals.ComputeCellNormalsOn()
angle_threshold = 80 # Degrees
normals.SetFeatureAngle(angle_threshold)
normals.SetSplitting(True)
normals.Update()

# Extract separated meshes
connectivity = vtk.vtkConnectivityFilter()
connectivity.SetInputData(normals.GetOutput())
connectivity.SetExtractionModeToAllRegions()
connectivity.Update()

print(connectivity.GetNumberOfExtractedRegions()) # outputs the correct number of regions

# Save separated meshes
for i in range(connectivity.GetNumberOfExtractedRegions()):
    writer = vtk.vtkSTLWriter()
    writer.SetFileName(f"output_{i}.stl")
    writer.SetInputData(connectivity.GetOutput(i))
    writer.Write()
```

I have tried the threshold filter too with no success. I am also open to other solutions (other libraries, other programming languages...) as long as it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to be simply using `connectivity.SetExtractionModeToSpecifiedRegions()` and `connectivity.AddSpecifiedRegion(i)` to get the different regions as separate outputs.